# shared libraries creating a soft link

Tags: c

Redhat 5.5
gcc version 4.1.2

I have a directory call lib, and in that directory I have all the shared libraries (about 30) that we get from our customer as we use their API. We link with this API.

directory structure:

```
/usr/CSAPI/lib
```

However, our customer will update their API so we get new libraries, normally about 3 or 4.

What I have been doing is when I get new libraries. Is to remove the old one and put in another directory. And replace them with the new libaries in the lib directory.

```
/usr/CSAPI/Old_libs
```

The new and old will have the same name. i.e.

```
libcs.so  < old
libcs.so  < new
```

Is there a better way to manage this? I was thinking of creating a soft line, but as the names are the same, I am not sure that this will work.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlinks are a very good way to handle this.  I would do something slightly differently.  I would create a directory structure like:

```
/usr/CSAPI/lib_v1
/usr/CSAPI/lib_v2
```

and in each of these I would put the actual files.  I would then create a separate directory:

```
/usr/CSAPI/lib
```

which only contains symlinks to the actual files in `lib_v1`, `lib_v2`, etc.

This way `lib` has the most current version, but if you need, you can use a previous version by simply changing your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Usually libraries are versioned, not just "the same name".

You'll have a file in your `/usr/lib` directory for each version:

```
/usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
/usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8.2.1
/usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8.2.2
```

Then you symlink the major library versions to the latest minor version:

```
/usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8 -> /usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8.2.2
```

The benefit of this is that API changes will add new files and update the symlinks, but if I need to specify a specific API version number, the file is still right there.

This isn't set in stone, so do whatever works for your release process :)

Comment: That's assuming the library is correctly developed.  I've used too many  libraries from companies that did not handle library versioning correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no version number. All the libraries just end with the shared library extension i.e. *.so. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, maybe use Klatchko's solution, except instead of symlinking individual files symlink the entire directory: /usr/CSAPI/lib -> /usr/CSAPI/lib_${current_version}.